# How to set alignment of span element and icons in list box?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

Is this possible to set span element alignment inside the list box..
i just try to create one small list box, i need to set right alignment of this span element and one more icon right side of the list. 
ha for example facebook chat list.

Fiddle code

**[FIDDLE HERE](https://jsfiddle.net/joelshah/6mt82o0h/)**

here is the example, exactly what i need.,

[image: Example image]

Here is my tried code

```js
$(document).ready(function() {
  $("#testId").keyup(function() {
    var x = document.getElementById('activeSpn');
    var y = document.getElementById('inActiveSpn');
    if ($(this).val() == "1") {
      x.style.display = 'block';
      y.style.display = 'none';
    } else {
      x.style.display = 'none';
      y.style.display = 'block';
    }
  });
});
```

```css
option {
  width: 100%;
}

.sch_submit {
  right: 0px !important;
  top: 13px;
}

.newSup {
  width: fit-content;
  position: relative;
  left: 40%;
}

.listbox {
  background: white;
  background: -webkit-linear-gradient(#ccc, white);
  background: -o-linear-gradient(#ccc, white);
  background: -moz-linear-gradient(#ccc, white);
  background: linear-gradient(#fff, white);
  border: 1px solid #ced4da;
  overflow: auto;
}

.listbox option {
  list-style: none;
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
}

.listbox option {
  padding: 10px;
  cursor: pointer;
}

.listbox option:hover {
  background-color: #bbb;
}

.listbox option.active {
  background: rgb(77, 176, 82);
}

option {
  -webkit-transition: background-color 200ms linear;
  -moz-transition: background-color 200ms linear;
  -o-transition: background-color 200ms linear;
  -ms-transition: background-color 200ms linear;
  transition: background-color 200ms linear;
}

.listbox::-webkit-scrollbar {
  width: 8px;
  border: 1px solid #ced4da;
}

.listbox::-webkit-scrollbar-track {
  background: rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.1);
}

.listbox::-webkit-scrollbar-thumb {
  background: gray;
}

.serch {
  width: 80%;
  position: relative;
  left: 60px;
}

#list1 {
  height: 440px;
  width: 100%;
  margin: 10px;
  text-align: center;
}

.selector {
  position: relative;
  left: 50px;
  margin-bottom: 20px;
}
```

```html
<html>

<head>
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.4.1/css/bootstrap.min.css">
  <script src="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.4.1/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
  <script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.4.1.slim.min.js"></script>
  <script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/popper.js@1.16.0/dist/umd/popper.min.js"></script>
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/font-awesome/4.7.0/css/font-awesome.min.css">
</head>

<body>
  <div class="row">
    <div class="col-6">
      <input class="form-control serch" id="supSearch" type="search" placeholder="Search..">
      <div class="selector">
        <!--  Green -->
        <span id="activeSpn" aria-label="Active Now" style="display: inline-block; background: rgb(66, 183, 42) none repeat scroll 0% 0%; border-radius: 50%; height: 10px; margin-left: 4px; width: 10px;"></span>

        <!-- red -->
        <span id="inActiveSpn" aria-label="inActive" style="display: inline-block; background: red none repeat scroll 0% 0%; border-radius: 50%;  height: 10px; margin-left: 4px; width: 10px;"></span>


        <select class="col-12 listbox" name="List_0" size="20" id="list1" multiple="multiple">
          <option class="fa fa-address-card-o" value="Komal ">Komal </option>
          <option class="fa fa-address-card-o" value="Ranjeet">Ranjeet</option>
          <option class="fa fa-address-card-o" value="Vishal ">Vishal </option>
          <option class="fa fa-address-card-o" value="Gaurav">Gaurav</option>
          <option value="Dhanpat">Dhanpat</option>
          <option value="joe">joe</option>
          <option value="Gowri">Gowri</option>
          <option value="shankar">shankar</option>
          <option value="tamil">tamil</option>
          <option value="raju">raju</option>
          <option value="sam">sam</option>
          <option value="jhon">jhon</option>
          <option value="sinns">sinns</option>
          <option value="ezhil">ezhil</option>
          <option value="rajput">rajput</option>
          <option value="padukone">padukone</option>
          <option value="siraj">siraj</option>
          <option value="rajesh">rajesh</option>
          <option value="ram">ram</option>
        </select>
      </div>
      <button type="button" class="btn add-btn newSup" id="supcreate">Create Supplier</button>
    </div>
    <div class="col-6">
      <div class="newClass" style="position:relative;left:30%; top:20%;">
        <label>Test:</label>
        <input type="text" class="testClass" id="testId">
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</body>

</html>
```

Comment: It can be done by flex.

Comment: @RevtiShah how? i tried but its wont work

Answer (score 0):

You can do it with a `position: fixed` and giving `top` and `bottom`. Check this fiddle https://jsfiddle.net/j6oxfy91/1/